# Java : ArrayList<HashMap<Integer,Integer>>

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

Is there a better approach to do the below in Java, without using external libraries.

I need to model group/child (tree like) structure of int (primitive). In Json

```
[{1,1}, {1,2}, {2,1},{3,1}]
```

I need to support addition/removal of elements (element is a pair {group, child} ) without duplication.

I am thinking of, keeping a data structure like.

```
ArrayList<HashMap<Integer,Integer>>
```

To add.

Iterate through ArrayList, check HashMap key and value against the value to insert, and insert if not exist.

To delete:

Iterate through ArrayList, check HashMap key and value against the value to delete, and delete if exist.

Is there a better data structure/approach with standard library.

---

As per one of the answer below, I made a class like this.
Please let me know anything to watchout. I am expecting (and going to try out) arraylist would handle add/remove correctly by using the equal method in KeyValue class. thanks.

```
 static class KeyValue {
        int groupPos;
        int childPos;

        KeyValue(int groupPos, int childPos) {
            this.groupPos = groupPos;
            this.childPos = childPos;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            if (this == o) return true;
            if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

            KeyValue keyValue = (KeyValue) o;

            if (childPos != keyValue.childPos) return false;
            if (groupPos != keyValue.groupPos) return false;

            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            int result = groupPos;
            result = 31 * result + childPos;
            return result;
        }
    }
```

Comment: In response to edit - `Set` (e.g. `TreeSet` (requires your class to extend java.lang.Comparable or a `Comparator` class given as input) / `HashSet`) would handle add/remove operations more efficiently than `ArrayList`.

Comment: in `equals()` instead of `if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;` use `if(! (o instanceof KeyValue)) return false;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand what you're trying to do, this may be simpler:

```
TreeMap<Integer,TreeSet<Integer>>
  or
HashMap<Integer,HashSet<Integer>>
```

So, rather than

```
[{1,1}, {1,2}, {2,1}, {3,1}]
```

you'd have

```
[{1, {1, 2}},
 {2, {1}},
 {3, {1}}]
```

Note that all 4 of the above classes automatically handles eliminating duplicates.

To add:

```
TreeMap<Integer, TreeSet<Integer>> map;
TreeSet<Integer> set = map.get(group);
if (set == null) // create it if it doesn't exist
{
  set = new TreeSet<Integer>();
  map.put(group, set);
}
set.add(child);
```

To remove:

```
TreeMap<Integer, TreeSet<Integer>> map;
TreeSet<Integer> set = map.get(group);
set.remove(child);
if (set.isEmpty()) // remove it if it is now empty
  map.remove(group);
```

Comment: thanks. I didn't do much Java, so never heard TreeMap and TreeSet. Will checkout. THanks

Comment: +1 thanks for the implementation. I like this approach. Will accept after test it. thanks again

Answer (score 1):

You may write a class with name `KeyValue` with two properties to hold group and child. Add `KeyValue` Objects to `ArrayList`. For CRUD operations, you may implement `equals` and `compare` in your KeyValue pair class.

Comment: `hashCode()` should also be implemented when `equals()` is overridden.

Comment: A more efficient implementation would be to use `Set<KeyValue>` (e.g. `HashSet<KeyValue>` or `TreeSet<KeyValue>`) instead of `ArrayList<KeyValue>`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `HashMap`, use a class called `Pair` with two fields `{group,child}` which will implement `Comparable` interface. Then implement/override its `equals()`, `hashCode()` and `compareTo()` methods. Then use either a `List<Pair>` or `Set<Pair>` depending on your needs to hold them. Having `compareTo()` implemented gives you the flexibility to sort `Pairs` easily too.

Answer (score 0):

I am new to the Data Structure world but I think we can use this based on the assumption that no two Set Objects will be similar

Set  validSet=new HashSet(); // Use Generics here

HashSet will provide a constant time for add/delete/contains

```
SomeObject{
     Integer parent ;
     Integer child;
     //define equals method based on your requirement
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Going By your Question i think that You want to show this line

```
[{1,1}, {1,2}, {2,1},{3,1}]
```

as

> Group 1-> 1 , 2 (from first two pair)
>     Group 2-> 1(from
>   third pair)
>      Group 3-> 1     (from fourth pair)

The data structure that suites most for storing this hierarchy is :

```
Map<Integer,Set<Integer>> map = new HashMap<Integer,Set<Integer>>();
```

Where the `key` part of map stores the group Number. And the `value` part of map is storing `TreeSet` which stores the children of that group.
As Example of code:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.ListIterator;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeSet;
class  TreeLike
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Map<Integer,Set<Integer>> map = new HashMap<Integer,Set<Integer>>();
        int groups[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
        //To add new group in map
        for (int i = 0 ; i < groups.length; i++)
        {
            Set<Integer> child = new TreeSet<Integer>();
            child.add(1);child.add(2);child.add(3);child.add(4);child.add(5);
            map.put(groups[i],child);
        }
        //To add new child(8) to a group (say group 1)
        Set<Integer> child = map.get(1);
        if (child != null)
        {
            child.add(8);
            map.put(1,child);
        }

        //To remove a child (say child 4) from group 3
        child = map.get(3);
        if (child != null)
        {
            child.remove(4);
            map.put(1,child);
        }
        //To Iterate through all trees
        Set<Map.Entry<Integer,Set<Integer>>> entrySet = map.entrySet();
        Iterator<Map.Entry<Integer,Set<Integer>>> iterator = entrySet.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext())
        {
            Map.Entry<Integer,Set<Integer>> entry = iterator.next();
            int group = entry.getKey();
            Set<Integer> children = entry.getValue();
            System.out.println("Group "+group+" children-->"+children);
        }
    }
}
```